# Self Hosted Azure DevOps Pipeline Agent fails with error Token Audience is not valid

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-aks

I have created a new token with Agent Pool *read and manage* permissions.
I have created a new agent pool *lnx_agent* wherein I have administrator role to manage it.
When I download tar file of agent linux x64 from this link https://vstsagentpackage-azureedge-net.o365.example-domain.defendernet.com/agent/2.171.1/vsts-agent-linux-x64-2.171.1.tar.gz, copy it to bastion host, unpack it and execute *./config.sh* with URL, PAT token, agent pool as *lnx_agent* and default agent name as *bastion_agent*; I have below error message.

```
[2020-06-28 20:24:35Z ERR  VisualStudioServices] POST request to https://vssps-dev-azure-com.o365.example-domain.defendernet.com/Example-Client/_apis/oauth2/token failed. HTTP Status: BadRequest, AFD Ref: Ref A: C7A934103EDF47B2B3E6F148516B35B5 Ref B: DB3EDGE1015 Ref C: 2020-06-28T20:24:35Z
[2020-06-28 20:24:35Z INFO VisualStudioServices] AAD Correlation ID for this token request: Unknown
[2020-06-28 20:24:35Z INFO VisualStudioServices] Finished operation Location.GetConnectionData
[2020-06-28 20:24:35Z INFO VisualStudioServices] Finished operation Location.GetConnectionData
[2020-06-28 20:24:35Z INFO VisualStudioServices] Finished operation Location.GetConnectionData
[2020-06-28 20:24:35Z ERR  Agent] Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.OAuth.VssOAuthTokenRequestException: The token audience is not valid https://vssps-dev-azure-com.o365.example-domain.defendernet.com/Example-Client/_apis/oauth2/token. Comparing to https://vssps-dev-azure-com.o365.example-domain.defendernet.com/Example-Client/_apis/oauth2/token; https://app-vssps-visualstudio-com.o365.example-domain.defendernet.com/Example-Client/_apis/oauth2/token.
```

Example-Client is my project and example-domain is my company name.
What does this mean *AAD Correlation ID for this token request: Unknown*?

Since my AKS cluster is private, all three options to connect to it from Azure release pipeline like  kubeconfig, service account and subscription fail. So, if I could configure self hosted agent in bastion host whose virtual network is peered with virtual network of private AKS cluster then I can successfully automate CD pipeline by running agent in this bastion host.

```
 az devops login --organization https://dev-azure-com.o365.example-domain.defendernet.com/Example-Client
Token:
Failed to store PAT using keyring; falling back to file storage.
You can clear the stored credential by running az devops logout.
Refer https://aka.ms/azure-devops-cli-auth to know more on sign in with PAT.
```

Comment: Can you access your Azure DevOps organization directly from this bastion host?

Comment: Yes, I have updated quesiton with command az devops login execution @AndyLi-MSFT

Comment: It appears that you cannot access the Azure DevOps organization. Can you login successfully via browser with user name and password? I mean access the ADO directly in browser.

Comment: I can access the Azure DevOps organization. I am not account owner as in my free credit account. However, I am a user in one of the subscriptions and active directory too.

Comment: Could you please confirm your Azure DevOps organization URL? Generally, the URL should be something like this:  `https://dev.azure.com/{organization}` or `https://{organization}visualstudio.com/`. But according to your description, it seems your URL is `https://dev-azure-com.o365.example-domain.defendernet.com/Example-Client`. We have never seen such an Azure DevOps URL.

Comment: URL update to https://dev.azure.com/Example-Client has resolved this issue. However, I consider URL https://dev-azure-com.o365.example-domain.defendernet.com/Example-Client to be a secure proxy and want to configure it with command ./config.sh --proxyurl <defendernet-url> --proxyusername "myuser" --proxypassword "mypass". Is my approach correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, please make sure you can access the Azure DevOps organization (`https://dev.azure.com/{organization}`) from the bastion host. Otherwise we cannot connect to the Azure DevOps services.

Secondly, please check if you are running a firewall or a proxy on the bastion host. If you're running an agent in a secure network behind a firewall, make sure the agent can initiate communication with the URLs and IP addresses mentioned in below documents.

- [What URLs does the agent need to communicate with?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=azure-devops#im-running-a-firewall-and-my-code-is-in-azure-repos-what-urls-does-the-agent-need-to-communicate-with)
- [How do I configure the agent to bypass a web proxy and connect to
  Azure Pipelines?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=azure-devops#how-do-i-configure-the-agent-to-bypass-a-web-proxy-and-connect-to-azure-pipelines)

Answer (score 0):

URL update from *https://dev-azure-com.o365.example-domain.defendernet.com/Example-Client* to *https://dev.azure.com/Example-Client* resolves this issue